# How do I Add a SKScene to a SCNNode Plane?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, arkit

I have completed the `raywenderlich.com` tutorial Building a Museum App with `ARKit` 2. I have tried to modify this app to put a `SKScene` on the anchor image instead of the `AVPlayer`.

All I really want to do is put an `SKShapeNode` on the image, but after doing research it looks like I have to create an `SKScene`, add the `SKShapeNode` to the `SKScene` and then add the `SKScene` to an `SCNPlane`.

> You can set a value for this property using any of the following types:
>
> - A color (NSColor/UIColor or CGColor), specifying a uniform color for the material’s surface
> - A number (NSNumber), specifying a uniform scalar value for the material's surface (useful for physically based properties such as metalness)
> - An image (NSImage/UIImage or CGImage), specifying a texture to be mapped across the material’s surface
> - An NSString or NSURL object specifying the location of an image file
> - A video player (AVPlayer) or live video capture preview (AVCaptureDevice, in iOS only)
> - A Core Animation layer (CALayer)
> - A texture (SKTexture, MDLTexture, MTLTexture, or GLKTextureInfo)
> - A SpriteKit scene (SKScene)
> - A specially formatted image or array of six images, specifying the faces of a cube map

Here is my modified version of the code:

```swift
private func handleFoundImage(_ imageAnchor: ARImageAnchor, _ node: SCNNode) {
    let name = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name!
    print("you found a \(name) image")
    
    let size = imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize
    
    let skScene = SKScene(size: size)
    print("SKSCENE FRAME: \(skScene.frame)")
    skScene.backgroundColor = .white
    
    let skShape = SKShapeNode(rectOf: size, cornerRadius: 5.0)
    skShape.fillColor = .blue
    skShape.strokeColor = .red
    skShape.lineWidth = 1.5
    
    skScene.addChild(skShape)
    
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.constant
    material.isDoubleSided = true
    material.diffuse.contents = skScene
    plane.materials = [material]
    
    let rectNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    rectNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
    node.addChildNode(rectNode)
}
```

When I run this on my iPhone and point it at the image, the App crashes, and I get the following stacktrace.

```
2019-04-15 22:32:28.650432-0600 ImageTracker[3807:1577260] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful
2019-04-15 22:32:29.238671-0600 ImageTracker[3807:1577061] [Accessibility] ****************** Loading GAX Client Bundle ****************
2019-04-15 22:32:29.362407-0600 ImageTracker[3807:1577061] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2019-04-15 22:32:29.364368-0600 ImageTracker[3807:1577061] Metal API Validation Enabled
2019-04-15 22:32:29.499256-0600 ImageTracker[3807:1577061] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2019-04-15 22:32:29.500912-0600 ImageTracker[3807:1577061] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
Point the camera at a dinsoaur.
you found a stegosaurus image
SKSCENE FRAME: (-0.0, -0.0, 0.10541000217199326, 0.06538714197231457)
<SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{-0, -0}, {0.10541000217199326, 0.065387141972314572}} anchor:{0, 0}
2019-04-15 22:32:37.189388-0600 ImageTracker[3807:1577292] validateTextureDimensions, line 1071: error 'MTLTextureDescriptor has width of zero.'
validateTextureDimensions:1071: failed assertion `MTLTextureDescriptor has width of zero.'
```

I'm not really sure what a `MTLTextureDescriptor` is or how to make the width a non-zero value.

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here, or is this even the right way to do this? Again, I just want to find an image, and overlay that with an `SKShapeNode`. If I have to do this with an `SKScene` that is fine, I just need help figuring out how to do that. If that is not the best way, can someone point me to the documentation where I can find the meter solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the width and height in `size` here `let size = imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize` is zero.

The size you get will be the `physicalSize` you set for your reference image, which sure is less than 1 meter. So when you use this as size for your `skScene`, you created it with size of both height and width equal to zero.

For example: if your reference image have physical size 10x15 cm, your `size` will have width 0.1 and height 0.15., which will be changed to zero.

I recommend:

```
let physicalSize = imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize
let size = CGSize(width: physicalSize.width * 1000, height: physicalSize.height * 1000)
```

Comment: Alok, you solution made it so that the app doesn't crash, but now, the skScene is (as expected) 1,000 times bigger than the anchor image. How can I make it fit to the dimensions of the image? When I used the AVPlayer (like in the tutorial project mentioned above), the movie fit exactly on the image with the correct dimensions. Is there a way to do this with an skScene?

Comment: You need physicalSize in your plane though.